# vba insert formula and get dynamic cell reference (cell reference of current row)?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to copy data from one sheet to another, this is inserted into a new row each time new data is copied. I want to be able to insert a formula into the cells D and E of the active/current row and use a dynamic cell reference. so if row 5 it will be A5 and if row 6 it will be A6 and so on.

I have tried using ActiveCell.Formula and DestRow and nothing works.

Can someone please show me how I can make this happen? Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If Target.Column = Range("Z1").Column And Range("Z" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "SUBMIT" Then
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim DestRow As Long
        Set ws1 = Sheets("Home")
        Set ws2 = Sheets("Statistics")
        DestRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws1.Range("B10").Copy
        ws2.Range("A" & DestRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        ws1.Range("B15").Copy
        ws2.Range("B" & DestRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        ws1.Range("B20").Copy
        ws2.Range("C" & DestRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        ws2.Range("D" & DestRow).Formula = "=IF(ISTEXT(A5),IF(E5 <>""Yes"",CONCATENATE(""NS"")&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9),D5),"""")"
        ws2.Range("E" & DestRow).Formula = "=IF(ISTEXT(A5),IF(ISTEXT(D5),""Yes"",""N/A""),"""")"
        ws1.Range("Y7").Copy
        ws2.Range("F" & DestRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        ws1.Range("H10").Copy
        ws2.Range("H" & DestRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include `DestRow` in your formula. I.e. the two lines in where you define the formula should be changed to:

```
ws2.Range("D" & DestRow).Formula = "=IF(ISTEXT(A" & DestRow & "),IF(E" & DestRow & " <>""Yes"",CONCATENATE(""NS"")&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9),D" & DestRow & "),"""")"
ws2.Range("E" & DestRow).Formula = "=IF(ISTEXT(A" & DestRow & "),IF(ISTEXT(D" & DestRow & "),""Yes"",""N/A""),"""")"
```